# Ajax 404 (Not Found) Looping through a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying NOT to repeat myself with the SAME code, so I thought I would use the jQuery `.each()` method.  Every time I reload the webpage, I get this ajax error:

[image]

The loop keeps turning it into an object.  Here's my code:

```
var counterColors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink',    'gray', 'brown'], $currentCounterColor;

$(counterColors).each(function() {
    $currentCounterColor = $(this);
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    cache: false,
                    success: function() {
                        $('#count_' + $currentCounterColor).fadeIn(300);
                    }
                });
                $currentCounterColor.load('./' + $currentCounterColor + '.php');
               var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
               $currentCounterColor.load('./' + $currentCounterColor + '.php');
              }, 60000);
          })
     })(jQuery);
});
```

I have 9 IDs like so:

```
#count_red
#count_orange
#count_yellow
... etc
```

Then I have 9 PHP files like so:

```
red.php
orange.php
yellow.php
```

I'm not familiar w/ this error..

Comment: Your `each` anon function doesn't have any arguments so how can you know what item you're on?

Comment: Would I put array as an argument then?

Comment: `$(this)` is most likely not what you think it is … You should not be using [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) here (that’s for looping over DOM nodes), but [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) instead. (And passing `jQuery` to the function as `$` also seems unnecessary.)

Comment: Ended up doing [this](http://cl.ly/image/1D3a2T362e1F); however, `v` isn't global so idk how i can `.load()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try like bellow. Because you are not taking any parameter to `each` and using `this` to refer. `this` will return an String like `{0:"r",1""e",2:"d"}`.

So when you are concatenating that it will return `#count_[object Object]` not `#count_red`.

I am just telling how you can proceed.

```
var counterColors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'pink',    'gray', 'brown'], $currentCounterColor;

$(counterColors).each(function(index,value) {
    $currentCounterColor = value;
    $('#count_' + $currentCounterColor).fadeIn(300); // here first time it will call the #count_red.load()

});
```

But in line bellow I'm not sure what you want to say

```
$currentCounterColor.load('./' + $currentCounterColor + '.php');
```

So just have look on the way, and change your implementation accordingly.

Comment: I was playing around with it, and did [this](http://cl.ly/image/1D3a2T362e1F).  What are your thoughts?

Comment: Says `$currentCounterColor` is not defined! "undefined is not a function"

Comment: @Matthew where how can I know without any code , add a demo so I can know.